# How do I make an img position fixed when you CLICK it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm trying to get it so that when you click a certain img it is fixed in that position until the page is refreshed; meaning that img will be stuck on the screen even as you scroll through other images and text.

I am very very noob at coding but I was researching this and can not get it to work; but I think it might go like some sort of Java script (onclick) activating a css style position: fixed?

EDIT: Solution given by JoshC below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload=function(){
 var img = document.getElementById('image');
 img.onclick = function(){
 this.style.position = 'fixed';
 }
 }

 </script>

 <style type="text/css">

 body {
height:2000px;
 }
 img { top:0; left:0; 
 }

 </style>

 <html>

 <body>

 <br><br><br><br><br>
 <img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please provide code or something that you have done.

Comment: @JoshC Your comment should be an answer =P

Comment: @AlcidesQueirozAguiar Alright. I just don't like *formally* answering questions like these. It's an answer now :p

Comment: I understand... I see two problems in this question: 1) It's too localized. 2) The user doesn't show any effort nor code...  =D

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? It's a perfectly legitimate question. I can find nothing wrong with it. Going to upvote and answer.

Comment: Sorry guys I move super slow but Josh and rvighne gave me something to try out..I will get back

Comment: Mine doens't work for some reason, and I double checked if any little things were off but everything is fine

Comment: @user3221810 Why'd you just post my answer in the question?

Comment: I wanted to show you how I have my code

Comment: @user3221810 Wrap it with `window.onload=function(){}`. [**live example**](http://joshcrozier.org/SO21273539) Inspect the elements of that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the element and use the [**`onclick`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) event:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
img.onclick = function(){
    this.style.position = 'fixed';
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDGbx/)

Comment: I feel ridiculous. You mean to tell me I've been editing the CSS class all this time when JS has a built in `.position` modifier? I'll go sink my head in shame now...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your guess. Put this code at the end of the `<body>` (or otherwise ensure that it runs after the body has loaded).

```
var img = document.getElementById('my_img');
img.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.style.position = "fixed";
});
```

And set the `id` attribute of your image to "my_img". You're not *that* bad a noob...